# How do I display multiple textfields to my labels?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm not sure if how I worded the question makes much sense so let me summarize.

I have 2 UITexfields and 2 UILabels.

I have it all working properly in terms of when I type into my first textField and hit return it will display my text.

Now I'm not sure how to get the same to apply to my other TextField and Label. I read that if I apply a tag to my textfield in Xcode "1" that I can apply tag "2" to my other textfield.

Here is the code I am using so when I press return it'll display textfield tag "1".

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        nameDisplay?.text = textField.text!
    }

    return true
}
```

So to completely round this out, I want to display both separate textfields on each separate label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an `else` to your `if`.

```
if textField.tag == 1 {
    nameDisplay.text = textField.text
} else {
    otherLabel.text = textField.text
}
```

Please note you do not need the `?` or `!` in that code.

Another option, if you have outlets for your text fields, is to do the following instead of bothering with tags:

```
if textField == someTextFieldOutlet {
    nameDisplay.text = textField.text
} else {
    otherLabel.text = textField.text
}
```

where `someTextFieldOutlet` is obviously needs to be the actual name of the appropriate text field outlet you have.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now. I only added the ? because I kept getting a thread error and the only fix i could find was using a ?.

Comment: If you were getting an error without the `?` then you probably didn't connect the label to your outlet in your storyboard.

Comment: Your fix worked perfectly for me thank you. I am still needing to read more to understand where my label isn't connected to my outlet in my storyboard because for some reason I just am not understanding. Thank you for the help!